# Why am I getting a MemoryError in Python for only 756 KiB?

Tags: python, machine-learning, memory, xgboost

I am trying to run the following binary classification Model with XGBoost. X has the features, and y has the binary classification.

```
X_trains, X_tests, y_trains, y_tests = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.05, random_state=56)
xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(max_depth=5, learning_rate=0.08, objective= 'binary:logistic',n_jobs=-1).fit(X_trains, y_trains)
print('Accuracy of XGB classifier on training set: {:.2f}'
       .format(xgb_model.score(X_trains, y_trains)))
print('Accuracy of XGB classifier on test set: {:.2f}'
       .format(xgb_model.score(X_tests[X_trains.columns], y_tests)))
```

I am getting a memory error, but only for 756 KiB. My laptop has far more RAM than that, so why is this happening? If it helps, I am running this in Jupyter Notebook.

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 X_trains, X_tests, y_trains, y_tests = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.05, random_state=56)
      2 xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(max_depth=5, learning_rate=0.08, objective= 'binary:logistic',n_jobs=-1).fit(X_trains, y_trains)
      3 print('Accuracy of XGB classifier on training set: {:.2f}'
      4        .format(xgb_model.score(X_trains, y_trains)))
      5 print('Accuracy of XGB classifier on test set: {:.2f}'

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)
   2150                      random_state=random_state)
   2151 
-> 2152         train, test = next(cv.split(X=arrays[0], y=stratify))
   2153 
   2154     return list(chain.from_iterable((_safe_indexing(a, train),

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in split(self, X, y, groups)
   1339         """
   1340         X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
-> 1341         for train, test in self._iter_indices(X, y, groups):
   1342             yield train, test
   1343 

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in _iter_indices(self, X, y, groups)
   1452         for i in range(self.n_splits):
   1453             # random partition
-> 1454             permutation = rng.permutation(n_samples)
   1455             ind_test = permutation[:n_test]
   1456             ind_train = permutation[n_test:(n_test + n_train)]

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.permutation()

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 756. KiB for an array with shape (193452,) and data type int32
```

Answer (score 1):

193452 * 4 bytes = 773808 bytes or about 773.8 KB
certainly 756 KB is not enough.

Check the source code, might be a dimension error.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you mean? Isn't 773 KB a very small number and very easy to allocate?

Comment: You have an array with shape (193452, ), every integer takes 4 bytes. So it needs 773 KB, but you only have 756 KB pre-allocated for those data. This is not about whether you got enough system RAM. Check your source code.

Comment: Pardon me, if I'm being blockheaded and not understanding, but your answer itself says the memory is only 773 KB, which is much less than available memory. Hence, it shouldn't throw up a MemoryError. Right?

Comment: Ok, got it now!